# malloc matrix which points to malloc arrays(C)

Tags: c, malloc

EDIT: I should not use [].

I have defined integer N with value 5 and *malloc.

```
#define N

void* malloc (size_t size);
```

...

```
int *p_mat=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int*) * N);
```

This is the matrix.

Now we need the arrays.

```
int p_arr1=(int)malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);

int p_arr2=(int)malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);

int p_arr3=(int)malloc(sizeof(int) * 1);

int p_arr4=(int)malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);

int p_arr5=(int)malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
```

So we have 5 arrays in different sizes. Now how do I make each pointer of the matrix point to the first cell in the array?

And another question, how do I send these variables to a function, I mean - what are the parameters in the function key?

Comment: 1. "how do I make each pointer of the matrix point to the first cell in the array" - they already do. 2 "what are the parameters in the function key" - WAT? 3. [Don't cast the return value of `malloc()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc). 4. The size you pass to `malloc()` is wrong, it should be `sizeof(*p_mat)` instead.

Comment: I'm not sure I got to the end of your idea.

2. I meant that each cell in **p_mat will point to the first cell of each array

Comment: 3. I meant when I make a func.

void print_number(int num); right? now how do I make a func that gets malloc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An array of N pointers to arrays-of-integers of different sizes....
(*Note* don't cast malloc return value in C - can hide errors - see [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)).

```
int i = 0;
int *p[N];
size_t sizes[] = { 4, 3, ..., 5 }; // N sizes

for(; i < N; ++i)
{
    p[i] = malloc(sizeof(int) * sizes[i]);
}
```

Now `p` is an array of pointers-to-int. `p[n]` is therefore the nth pointer-to-int in the array.

`int *p[n]` would look something like this in memory:

```
int *p[n]
+-----+
|     | <------- Each element of the array is a pointer-to-an-integer
|     |
+-----+
|     |
|     |
+-----+
.
.
.
+-----+
|     |
|     |
+-----+
```

When we then do `p[n] = malloc(sizeof(int) * sizes[i])`, we are saying that the pointer `p[n]` (remember each element of the array `p` is a pointer), points to a block of memory the size of `sizes[i]` integers. So you get something like...

```
+-----+                                            +------+------+ ... +------+
|p[n] |-------- array element is a pointer to ---> | int1 | int2 |     | intm |
|     |                                            |      |      |     |      |
+-----+                                            +------+------+ ... +------+
.
.
.
+-----+
|     |
|     |
+-----+
```

So when you write `p[n]` you are accessing a pointer to the array of ints you `malloc()`ed...

Later on in your code you must remember to `free()` the memory allocated :)

```
for(; i < N; ++i)
{
    free(p[i]);
}
```

Hope this helps...

EDIT: Didn't read the last bit of your question but wilsonmichaelpatrick has answered it...

EDIT: Note, btw, that I'm not checking `malloc()` return for `NULL` and handling the possible error a this is just an example...

If you do not want to declare `int *p[N];` on the stack and would prefer the heap, try the following...

```
int i = 0;
size_t sizes[] = { 4, 3, ..., 5 }; // N sizes
int **p = malloc(sizeof(int *) * N);
for(; i < N; ++i)
{
    p[i] = malloc( sizeof(int) * sizes[i]);
}

...
...

for(; i < N; ++i)
{
    free(p[i]);
}

free(p);
```

EDIT: Use `#include <stdlib.h>` for definitions of `free()` and `malloc()`

Comment: This is nice but it's ain't what I meant.I meant that I'll create a malloc and it will point to arrays

Comment: So do you want to replace `*p[N];` with int `**p = malloc(sizeof(int *) * N);`?

Comment: I think it's ok. but the free function is undefined

Comment: Are you doing a `#include <stdlib.h>`? That header file should define `malloc()` and `free()` for you...

Comment: I did: int sizes=(int)malloc(sizeof(int) * N); and free(sizes);

And now it says 'int is imcopetible with (void)*'
WHATTTTTTTT

Comment: malloc returns a **pointer**. You cast that pointer to an integer in your example. So free() will complain. The compiler is warning you that you are not trying to free a pointer... the types don't match :) `int` cannot be cast to `void *` without an explicit cast. Note however, that you *shouldn't* really be doing that anyway. Keep your pointers as pointers :)

Comment: Have updated the answer... hopefully this is more clear as to how pointers work :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29924/discussion-between-jimbo-and-ofek-t)

Answer (score 2):

EDIT:  First, let's start with some corrections:

```
int **p_mat=(int**)malloc(sizeof(int*) * N);
int *p_arr1=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 4);
int *p_arr2=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 3);
int *p_arr3=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 1);
int *p_arr4=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 2);
int *p_arr5=(int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * 5);
```

Now, you can make each element of the matrix point to the first element of the array like this:

```
p_mat[0] = p_arr1;
p_mat[1] = p_arr2;
p_mat[2] = p_arr3;
p_mat[3] = p_arr4;
p_mat[4] = p_arr5;
```

Now if you want to pass this to a function, you can just have

```
int SomeFunction(int **theMatrix)
{
    /* Get third element of second row */
    int nSecondElementFirstRow = theMatrix[1][2]; /* same as p_arr2[2] above */
}
```

and call

```
SomeFunction(p_mat);
```

Specific to your comment, you could have a function:

```
void print_number(int n)
{
    printf("%d\n", n);
}
```

and call it like this:

```
 print_number(p_mat[1][2]);
```

to print out the third element of second row; that would print out p_arr2[2].  You could set `p_arr2[2] = 12345;` right after you malloc p_arr2 to test.

Finally, many comments I've just read suggest not casting the results of malloc as I have done:  [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: `int *p_mat` is a pointer to integer so I think `p_mat[0] = p_arr1` only works if `sizeof(int) == sizeof(int *)` and also isn't quire what is intended? `p_mat[0] = p_arr1` is trying to assign an integer to a pointer-to-integer. I suspect this would cause a compiler warning.

Comment: @Jimbo Yeah, I didn't see that, I just put a edit to correct that at the top, taking an educate guess at what the poster intended.  Thanks though, good eye.

Comment: To the second answer: the function is yelling that it's doesn't **int it's (void)p_mat(int**)

Comment: @Ofek .T. Try `print_number(p_mat[1][2]);` if you're calling it from where you've malloc'ed p_mat.  (I just edited that above, before I had it called from `SomeFunction`).  Also make sure p_mat is `int**` not `int*` (it's in my corrections at the top).

Answer (score 1):

If you want to associate each array to the first one:

```
p_mat[0] = p_arr1;
p_mat[1] = p_arr2;
//(...)
p_mat[4] = p_arr5;
```

Comment: Edited, question. +I can't use [].

Comment: And I get an error:  7 IntelliSense: a value of type "void (*)(int *p)" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "int" d:\users\user-pc\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\class 7\class 7\fml.c 23

Comment: `int *p_mat` is a pointer to integer so I think `p_mat[0] = p_arr1` only works if `sizeof(int) == sizeof(int *)` and also isn't quire what is intended? `p_mat[0] = p_arr1` is trying to assign an integer to a pointer-to-integer.